Getting this error in android Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'
Installed react-native-reanimated getting the following error.

Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: ninja: error: '/Users/kushagrawadhwa/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bfc1e5fee0d00c73b42e81d693b94d66/transformed/jetified-hermes-android-0.73.7-debug/prefab/modules/libhermes/libs/android.arm64-v8a/libhermes.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/46324r4y/obj/arm64-v8a/libreanimated.so', missing and no known rule to make it
72 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 56 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.


com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/kushagrawadhwa/Desktop/Demo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/46324r4y/arm64-v8a'
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
/Users/kushagrawadhwa/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja 
-C 
/Users/kushagrawadhwa/Desktop/Demo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/46324r4y/arm64-v8a 
reanimated
from /Users/kushagrawadhwa/Desktop/Demo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android
ninja: error: '/Users/kushagrawadhwa/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bfc1e5fee0d00c73b42e81d693b94d66/transformed/jetified-hermes-android-0.73.7-debug/prefab/modules/libhermes/libs/android.arm64-v8a/libhermes.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/46324r4y/obj/arm64-v8a/libreanimated.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 8m 53s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/kushagrawadhwa/Desktop/Demo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/46324r4y/arm64-v8a' [0/2] Re-checking globbed directories... C++ build system [build] failed while executing: /Users/kushagrawadhwa/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \ -C \ /Users/kushagrawadhwa/Desktop/Demo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/46324r4y/arm64-v8a \ reanimated from /Users/kushagrawadhwa/Desktop/Demo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android ninja: error: '/Users/kushagrawadhwa/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bfc1e5fee0d00c73b42e81d693b94d66/transformed/jetified-hermes-android-0.73.7-debug/prefab/modules/libhermes/libs/android.arm64-v8a/libhermes.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/46324r4y/obj/arm64-v8a/libreanimated.so', missing and no known rule to make it * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 8m 53s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I am trying to run the android without any errors.
Already tried changing the version of react-native and package version of react-native-reanimated
